# Time Complexity of algorithm with functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have problems with determining the time complexity of the algorithm. I know some basics of determination, but I have never encountered a problem of this complexity before. The algorithm is as follows:

```
f(n): O(log(n)), Ω(1)
g(n): O(n), Ω(log2)
(n))
1 A(n) {
2    int x = 0;
3    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
4       x = x + f (n) * g(n);
5       if (f(n) + g(n) > n * n) {
6          for (int j = n; j > 0; j = j/2) {
7             x = x * f(n) * f(n) * g(n) * g(n);
8          }
9        }
10    }
11    return x;
12 }
```

I know that the complexity of the first loop `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` is `O(n)`, I also know that the complexity of the loop `for (int j = n; j > 0; j = j/2)` is `O(log n)`, express as `x` is `O(1)`, but I do not understand this at all with these functions `f(n)` and `g(n)` whose complexity is given. That confuses me, as does this if condition. If anyone is willing to help me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Are you looking for the time complexity of *A*, or the complexity of its return value?

Comment: @Berthur Complexity of A.

Comment: That can mean two things :) *A* is a function, so you can ask for its complexity (how big is *x*?) or its time complexity (how much time does it take to execute *A*) asymptotically wrt. *n*.

Comment: @Berthur Yes, I need to observe the asymptotic behavior of algorithms when n (input size) is unbounded is growing. Determine the nearest upper (big O) complexity limit of alghorithm?

Comment: That can still mean two things. Example: The function `f(n) = n` has complexity *O(n)* but as an algorithm it has **time** complexity *O(1)*.